# Check whether $ g(x)=tf(x)+(1-t)f(0)^{\frac{1}{1-t}}f(x)^{\frac{t}{t-1}}$ is concave in $x$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, proof-verification, derivatives, continuity

**Question:**

I want to check whether the following function is concave in $x>0$
\begin{equation*}
    g(x)=tf(x)+(1-t)f(0)^{\frac{1}{1-t}}f(x)^{\frac{t}{t-1}}.
\end{equation*}
I assume that $x\geq0$ and $t\in(0, 1)$. Note that $f(x)>f(0)>0$ for all $x>0$.

I impose the following conditions: $f'(x)>0$ and $f''(x)<0$ for $x>0$.

As an example, I know that $g$ is concave for $f(x)=1+\sqrt{x}$, but want to see whether this is true more generally.

**Answer Attempt:**

The first and second order conditions are
\begin{equation*}
    g'(x)=tf'(x)-tf(0)^{\frac{1}{1-t}}f'(x)f(x)^{\frac{1}{t-1}}
    =tf'(x)\bigg[1-\bigg(\frac{f(0)}{f(x)}\bigg)^{\frac{1}{1-t}}\bigg]
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{align*}
    g''(x)&=tf''(x)-tf(0)^{\frac{1}{1-t}}f''(x)f(x)^{\frac{1}{t-1}}+\frac{t}{1-t}f(0)^{\frac{1}{1-t}}f'(x)^2f(x)^{\frac{1}{t-1}-1},\\
    &=tf''(x)\bigg[1-\bigg(\frac{f(0)}{f(x)}\bigg)^{\frac{1}{1-t}}\bigg]+\frac{t}{1-t}\bigg(\frac{f'(x)^2}{f(x)}\bigg)\bigg(\frac{f(0)}{f(x)}\bigg)^{\frac{1}{1-t}}.
\end{align*}

**Edit:**
The rest of my previous attempt at a proof was shown to be incorrect by @GReyes so I have removed it.

Any advice would be most appreciated!

Comment: Can you please make more clear what your assumptions on $f$ are?

Comment: I am not sure how to do so.  I believe I have stated all relevant conditions in my question, is there someway that I can clarify the assumptions more specifically?

As in the question, $f$ is increasing, concave and positive when $x=0$.

Comment: and, apparently, also $f'(0)=f''(0)=0$ and strict concavity??

Comment: Yes, that is also in the question.  I will try and clarify but which part needs clarification? Does my example of $f(x)=1+\sqrt{x}$ not help clarify the conditions?

Comment: It seems to me that your conditions are contradictory. if $f'(0)=0$ and $f''(x)<0$ for $x>0$ then $f'(x)<0$ for $x>0$. This is not compatible with your assumption on $f'$.

Comment: In your example $f'(0)$ does not exist

Comment: Okay great thank you, now I understand the problem.  The conditions $f'(0)=0$ is not necessary for my problem, I just used it (incorrectly) in my attempt to show concavity.

Comment: Do you want $g$ to be concave for all values of $t$ ($0 \le t \le 1$) or just a specific one?

Comment: Also, $g$ is not concave for the given $f$.

Comment: All values of $t\in(0,1)$.  By given $f$ do you mean the example? If so it is concave for all $x>0$.  This is readily seen using Desmos and I have a proof on one of my other questions on this site.